# Month on month comparison using python

Tags: python, pandas

We have below dataset having month on month data and need to determine percentage between month.

```
ID  Jan 1   Feb 2   Mar 3
1   50  40  60  55  45  37
2   100 92  100 80  100 30
3   110 89  110 0   120 119
4   200 195 0   0   125 120
5   0   0   0   0   125 120
```

percentage need to calculate by= 1/Jan*100
If that percentage below 90 then we need to mark that column in our result column as comma separated.

Expected result:

```
 ID Jan 1   %_1   Feb   2   %_2     Mar 3   %_3     Result
1   50  40  80    60    55  91.67   45  37  82.22   1,3
2   100 92  92    100   80  80     100  30  30      2,3
3   110 89  80.91 110   0   0      120  119 99.17   1,2
4   200 195 97.5  0     0   0      125  120 96      1,2
5   0   0   0     0     0   0      125  120 96      1,2
```

Comment: What is `print (df.head(5).to_dict())` ? There is `MultiIndex` ? Or columns has values like `50 40` ?

Comment: columns has values like 50 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

```
L = {1: 91.0, 2: 105.0, 3: 96.0, 4: 126.0, 5: 125.0, 6: 139.0, 7: 120.0, 
         8: 145.0, 9: 116.0, 
     'Apr': 134.0, 'Aug': 150.0, 'Feb': 108.0, 'Jan': 91.0, 
          'Jul': 128.0, 'Jun': 147.0, 
     'Mar': 102.0, 'May': 134.0, 'Sep': 116.0, 'id': 494} 
L1 = {1: 10.0, 2: 105.0, 3: 96.0, 4: 126.0, 5: 20.0, 6: 139.0, 7: 120.0, 8: 52.0, 9: 116.0, 
     'Apr': 134.0, 'Aug': 150.0, 'Feb': 108.0, 'Jan': 91.0, 'Jul': 128.0, 'Jun': 147.0,
     'Mar': 102.0, 'May': 134.0, 'Sep': 12.0, 'id': 496}
df = pd.DataFrame([L, L1])
```

---

```
#convert id to index
df1 = df.set_index('id')
#test if columns names are months
mask = pd.to_datetime(df1.columns, format='%b', errors='coerce').notna()

#convert months to categoricals and sorting
df2 = df1.loc[:, mask]
cats = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr','May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
df2.columns = pd.CategoricalIndex(df2.columns, categories=cats, ordered=True)
df2 = df2.sort_index(axis=1)
# print (df2)

#extract not months columns
df3 = df1.loc[:, ~mask]
# print (df3)

#VERY IMPORTANT TEST IF BOTH LENGTHS MATCH
print (len(df2.columns) == len(df3.columns))
```

---

```
#divide by df2 converted to numpy
df4 = df3.div(df2.to_numpy()).mul(100)
# print (df4)

#created new column by dot for matrix multiplication
res = df4.lt(90).dot(df4.columns.astype(str) + ',').str.strip(',')
# print (res)

#dict for replace columns names
d = dict(zip(df3.columns, '%_' + df2.columns.astype(str) + ' ' + df3.columns.astype(str)  ))
# print (d)

#join together
df = pd.concat([df3, df4.rename(columns=d), res.rename('Result')], axis=1)
# print (df)

#change ordering
order = [i for x in df3.columns for i in (x,  d[x])]  + ['Result']
# print (order)

df = df[order]
```

---

```
print (df)
        1     %_Jan 1      2    %_Feb 2     3    %_Mar 3      4    %_Apr 4  \
id                                                                           
494  91.0  100.000000  105.0  97.222222  96.0  94.117647  126.0  94.029851   
496  10.0   10.989011  105.0  97.222222  96.0  94.117647  126.0  94.029851   

         5    %_May 5      6    %_Jun 6      7  %_Jul 7      8    %_Aug 8  \
id                                                                          
494  125.0  93.283582  139.0  94.557823  120.0    93.75  145.0  96.666667   
496   20.0  14.925373  139.0  94.557823  120.0    93.75   52.0  34.666667   

         9     %_Sep 9 Result  
id                             
494  116.0  100.000000         
496  116.0  966.666667  1,5,8
```

Comment: I am getting following error.
AttributeError: ('Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas', 'occurred at index Apr')

Comment: @Amol - What is `print (df.columns.tolist()[:5])` ?

Comment: output
['ID','Apr', 'Aug', 'Feb', 'Jan', 'Jul', 'Jun']...
Shall I need to rearrange that position??. and after that it show 1,2,3..

Comment: @Amol - So `1,2,3` not exist like in input data in question?

Comment: @Amol - What is `print (df.iloc[0].to_dict())` ?

Comment: {1: 91.0, 2: 105.0, 3: 96.0, 4: 126.0, 5: 125.0, 6: 139.0, 7: 120.0, 8: 145.0, 9: 116.0, 'Apr': 134.0, 'Aug': 150.0, 'Feb': 108.0,  'Jan': 91.0, 'Jul': 128.0, 'Jun': 147.0, 'Mar': 102.0, 'May': 134.0, 'Sep': 116.0, 'id': 494}

Comment: @Amol - OK, my solution cannot working with this data, please let me some time for new solution.

Comment: @Amol - Is possible in data are 2 times `Jan` or `Feb`, months? Or maximal 12 unique monts in columns names?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223742/discussion-between-amol-and-jezrael).

Comment: @Amol - What is expected outpu if input is `L = {1: 91.0, 2: 105.0, 3: 96.0, 4: 126.0, 5: 125.0, 6: 139.0, 7: 120.0, 8: 145.0, 9: 116.0, 'Apr': 134.0, 'Aug': 150.0, 'Feb': 108.0, 'Jan': 91.0, 'Jul': 128.0, 'Jun': 147.0, 'Mar': 102.0, 'May': 134.0, 'Sep': 116.0, 'id': 494} 
df = pd.DataFrame([L, L])` ?

Comment: expected output
{'1': 91, '2': 105, '3': 96, '4': 126, '5': 125, '6': 139, '7': 120, '8': 145, '9': 116, 'Apr': 134, 'Apr_per': 94.02985075, 'Aug': 150, 'Feb': 108, 'ID': 0, 'Jan': 91, 'Jul': 128, 'Jun': 147, 'Jun_per': 94.55782313, 'Mar': 102, 'May': 134, 'Sep': 116, 'aug_per': 96.66666667, 'feb_per': 97.22222222, 'id': 494, 'jan_per': 100, 'jul_per': 93.75, 'mar_per': 94.11764706, 'may_per': 93.28358209, 'result': 'good', 'sep_aug': 100}
if its average below 90% then need to add that month in comma separated form like
result:1,2,6,8